# AlertDialog in View class?

Tags: android, view, android-alertdialog

I created the class extending View. Now I want to show AlertDialog when user do something.
How can I do that?

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

This code isn't working, because "this" variable should be an Activity, but "this" in my class is "Drawable".

Comment: if you have a context in your custom View, use it in place of 'this' keyword

Comment: 12-06 20:28:29.128: E/AndroidRuntime(9133): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Answer (score 0):

Get your context into your class and replace that instance with "this".

Comment: 12-06 20:28:29.128: E/AndroidRuntime(9133): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Looks like you are running this code on a different thread.   I will need to see more code to understand what is going on.

All UI stuff needs to run on the main/UI thread.